# Encrypting the code using AES . ESP32

Tags: esp32

I am trying to figure it out. Why are my encryption and decryption not correct?

The used library for AES:

https://github.com/DanielVukelich/Arduino-AES

This is for testing encrypt and decrypt.
[//https://www.hanewin.net/encrypt/aes/aes-test.htm](https://www.hanewin.net/encrypt/aes/aes-test.htm)

```
#include "Rij_Consts.h"
#include "Rijndael.h"
   
    
    void setup() {
     
      Serial.begin(115200);
     
      //mbedtls_aes_context aes;
    
      unsigned char iv[16] = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};
      
      //char * key = "abcdefghijklmnop";
      //const unsigned char key[16];
      const unsigned char key[16] = {0xE8,0xE9,0xEA,0xEB,0xED,0xEE,0xEF,0xF0,0xF2,0xF3,0xF4,0xF5,0xF7,0xF8,0xF9,0xFA};
      //unsigned char key[16] = {0xFA,0xF9,0xF8,0xF7,0xF5,0xF4,0xF3,0xF2,0xF0,0xEF,0xEE,0xED,0xEB,0xEA,0xE9,0xE8};//กลับ
     
      //char *input = "Tech tutorials x";
     const unsigned char input[16] ={0x01,0x4B,0xAF,0x22,0x78,0xA6,0x9D,0x33,0x1D,0x51,0x80,0x10,0x36,0x43,0xE9,0x9A};
      //unsigned char input[16] ={0x9A,0xE9,0x43,0x36,0x10,0x80,0x51,0x1D,0x33,0x9D,0xA6,0x78,0x22,0xAF,0x4B,0x01};//กลับ
    
      
      unsigned char output[16]; //6743C3D1519AB4F2CD9A78AB09A511BD ต้องได้ตามนี้
    
    
      printf("Testing ECB mode:\n");
    
      printf("Original Plaintext:\n");
      for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        printf("%2.2X ", input[i]);
      }
     
      unsigned char keys[176];//for 128
      
      Schedule_Keys(AES_128, key, 16, keys);
      printf("\n\nKEYs:\n");
      for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        printf("%2.2X ", keys[i]);
      }
    
      Encrypt(AES_128, input, 16, keys, output);
    
    
    
      printf("\n\nCiphertext:\n");
     for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        char str[16];
        sprintf(str, "%2.2X ", output[i]);
        Serial.print(str);
     }
    
    
    Decrypt(AES_128, input, 16, keys, output);
    printf("\n\nCiphertext:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        char str[16];
        sprintf(str, "%2.2X ", output[i]);
        Serial.print(str);
    }
    }
     
    void loop() {}
```

My output :
[image]

You can see my encryption and decryption not correct.

I tried to reconstruct the full code.

```
#include "Rij_Consts.h"
#include "Rijndael.h"

//https://www.hanewin.net/encrypt/aes/aes-test.htm   สำหรับเทสเทียบ

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(115200);
    unsigned char iv[16] = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};
    const unsigned char key[16] = {0xE8,0xE9,0xEA,0xEB,0xED,0xEE,0xEF,0xF0,0xF2,0xF3,0xF4,0xF5,0xF7,0xF8,0xF9,0xFA};
    const unsigned char plainText[16] ={0x01,0x4B,0xAF,0x22,0x78,0xA6,0x9D,0x33,0x1D,0x51,0x80,0x10,0x36,0x43,0xE9,0x9A};
    unsigned char cipherText[16]; //6743C3D1519AB4F2CD9A78AB09A511BD Answer
    printf("Testing ECB mode:\n");

    
      printf("Original Plaintext:\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
                  Serial.printf("%2.2X ", plainText[i]);
      }
        unsigned char keys[176];//for 128
        
        Schedule_Keys(AES_128, key, 16, keys);
            printf("\n\nKEYs:\n");
                for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
                    Serial.printf("%2.2X ", keys[i]);
      }

      
      Encrypt(AES_128, plainText, 16, keys,cipherText );
          Serial.printf("\n\nCiphertext:\n");
              for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                    Serial.printf("%2.2X ", cipherText[i]);
      } 
      unsigned char decryptedText[16];
      
        Decrypt(AES_128,cipherText , 16, keys, decryptedText);

          Serial.printf("\n\ndecryptedText:\n");
              for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                    Serial.printf("%2.2X ", decryptedText[i]);
}
}
 
  
void loop() {}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t have time to write a complete answer, but it looks like you’re attempting to  “decrypt” the (unencrypted) cleartext, not the ciphertext. The input of `Decrypt` should be the output of `Encrypt`.

Comment: Could you pls explain a little more about Encrypt and Decrypt? I'm kinda confused. But thanks for the comment

Comment: I want to Encrypt the code correctly first. but I don't know what to do. I keep missing and being wrong. My Encrypt is not correct that makes my Decrypt wrong too :<<<.

Comment: This is mainly a coding issue and not specific to Arduino. However, see my answer.

Comment: Could you pls send me the full code of ur answer to my Gmail? I want to compare to mine what did I do wrong. siripaiboon.J61@rsu.ac.th

Comment: With my answer you should be able to reconstruct the full code.

Comment: I'm outside, not back home yet. And appreciate you for helping me. You just came in the clutch.

Comment: I tried to reconstruct the code today. but My encrypt is still not correct at all. Do I really miss something in my new code. I did change as u said about Input, Output. My new code in the post.

Comment: Your reconstructed code as posted in your question runs exactly like it should on an ESP32 and also on an ESP8266. You seem to have renamed *"Rijndael_Consts.h"* to *"Rij_Consts.h"* so I had to fix that, but that could not have caused your issue. The output in my case was a correct Ciphertext and Decrypted text. How did you install the library?

Comment: Hmm, Interesting. I did not install it by myself. I got this library as WIN.RAR from my friend. I'll try to install it again. I'll let you know. After I install the new library.

Comment: I have a question. Why do my Encryption/Decryption not match the website we use to compare ? Even I use the same AES128-ECB :< https://www.hanewin.net/encrypt/aes/aes-test.htm

Comment: I don't know. You might try re-downloading and re-installing the library from Github.

Comment: Finally, I can encrypt the code correctly. Thanks for the advice. I tried re-installing from the library. It actually worked.

Comment: I tried to download the library from Github, but there is a file missing. Could you please provide another link?

Comment: @YathribElsiddig There are Rjindael.c, Rjindael.h, Rjindael_Consts. there is no file missing in the library. but you have to read  "README"  carefully first before you use his library with your project and I'm afraid that I don't have that link.  It was like 2 years ago

Comment: Maybe you try to redownload it like me. I had problem with download library before. you can see my post up there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues with your code.

As mentioned in my comment, `Decrypt ()` expects the Cipher Text as input and generates the Decrypted text as an output. However, in your code you're using the Plain text (which you confusingly named "input") as an input. The correct input should be your Cipher Text (which is the output from the `Encrypt ()` function and which you called "output"). Please read the documentation of the AES library.

I suggest the following changes to your code to get it working:

Replace the part of your code, following `Decrypt (...)` until the end of `setup()` with the following code:

```
unsigned char decryptedText[16];
Decrypt(AES_128, output, 16, keys, decryptedText);

Serial.printf("\n\ndecryptedText:\n");
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    Serial.printf("%2.2X ", decryptedText[i]);
}
```

I would also suggest you name your variables to avoid confusion, for example you could replace `input[]` with `plainText[]` and `output[]` with `cipherText[]`. Some of your Hex output code is also unnecessarily complex and could do with some restructuring.

I've compiled and run the above changes with your code on an ESP32 and it produces the expected Cipher text and correctly decrypts it. It produces the following output:

```
00:21:01.583 -> Testing ECB mode:
00:21:01.583 -> Original Plaintext:
00:21:01.630 -> 01 4B AF 22 78 A6 9D 33 1D 51 80 10 36 43 E9 9A 
00:21:01.630 -> 
00:21:01.630 -> KEYs:
00:21:01.630 -> E8 E9 EA EB ED EE EF F0 F2 F3 F4 F5 F7 F8 F9 FA 
00:21:01.630 -> 
00:21:01.630 -> Ciphertext:
00:21:01.630 -> 67 43 C3 D1 51 9A B4 F2 CD 9A 78 AB 09 A5 11 BD 
00:21:01.630 -> 
00:21:01.630 -> decryptedText:
00:21:01.630 -> 01 4B AF 22 78 A6 9D 33 1D 51 80 10 36 43 E9 9A
```

In your question you mention that the generated Cipher text is not as expected. I can't help you with that, as I can't reproduce it.